# datastax cassandra scheduled replication

Tags: cassandra, replication, datastax

In datastax i want to replicate two node( from Node A to Node B at same server) on scheduled time not automatically.Kindly help me how to do it.

- Data will be inserted in Node A and Node B is for search.
- Once in the day at scheduled time data replicate from Node A to Node B.
- Both node are located on same server.

Comment: Have you even read how cassandra works? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_HTdrTgGNs

Answer (score 0):

DataStax/Cassandra does not do scheduled backups. Replication is done automatically when your data is written to the cluster. Also, each node should be its own individual server.